# How can I convince emacs C++ mode than my less than isn't a template parameter?

Tags: c++, emacs

This problem has annoyed me for years, and I'm wondering if anyone has had a solution. The problem is that in C++ mode, it seems like emacs cant decide if the  `<` operator is "less than" or "begin template parameters", which messes up the auto-indent feature. Consider something like this:

```
bool foo() {
  return X < Y &&
             Y < Z;
}
```

That Y is way over to the right and if I run `c-set-offset` (with `C-c C-o`) on the line with `Y < Z`, it tells me that the current line offset is `template-args-cont`. The worst part is that any code below this, including other functions, will have totally screwed up tabbing. Usually I just carefully manually space the beginning of the next function.

EDIT: To confirm, the following code indents correctly:

```
bool foo() {
  return X == Y &&
    Y == Z;
}
```

EDIT 2: I have some custom style and offset stuff, but even starting emacs with -q to ignore my .emacs file shows the same problem. I'm currently using version:

```
GNU Emacs 24.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.36)
 of 2012-06-10 on bob.porkrind.org
```

On mac OS X 10.8 but I'm sure I've seen the same problem on ubuntu, but I'd have to go double check versions.

Has anyone found a solution to this? Corey discovered that adding parens `(X < Y)` is a workaround.

Comment: Are you sure that is the issue? That could just be that it produces that level of indentation for the second and later lines in an expression that expands across multiple lines... can you add a similar expression substituting `<` with, way `==` and see if it indents the same?

Comment: The only way I've ever found answers to these questions is by reading the elisp code for myself.

Comment: Which c++ mode are you running in? I use `ellemtel` and can't reproduce this behavior for your example. Also, I'm curious what happens if you put parentheses around `(X < Y)` and `(Y < Z)`?

Comment: @Corey Interesting, I see the same problem with `ellemtel` although I normally use `linux`. I also tried ignoring my .emacs and using the defaults, but that didn't help. Adding the parens actually fixes the problem! Thanks! I can do this form now on, but its still frustrating that it exists in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

This looks more like C++ issue than that of `cc-mode`. The latter probably could use some smarter heuristics to handle simpler issues, like yours, but in general this less-than/template-open conflict is very hard to solve without knowing if `X` is a template.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

#ifdef TEMPLATE
template <int I>
int X(int arg)
{
  return I + arg;
}
#else
int X = -1;
#endif

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  const int Y = 0;

  int foo = 1, bar = 2;

  cout << (X < Y && 10 > (foo + bar)) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

It prints `3` if `#define TEMPLATE` is into the source and `1` otherwise, and should you break the `cout << ...` line at `&&`-op there's no way to figure out proper indentation unless you know exact build environment for that file.